# Install SQL Server Express and configure database with ClickOnce?

Tags: clickonce

I'm going to be publishing my Windows Form Application. It is going to be requiring an installation of SQL Server Express. Is it possible for ClickOnce to install SQL Server Express together with the application I coded?

Additionally: If, it is possible then can it also setup a database with its tables and structures?

Answer (score 0):

Try Setup factory  http://www.indigorose.com/products/setup-factory/ . I think clickonce not possible to achieve this.